# calculate with php service hours and intervall

Tags: php, math

i want to know if a value is almost at a point.

like i have

```
$hours 
$next_hours
$service_interval

// $hours = 49700 
// $next_hours = 50000
// $service_interval = 500
```

i want to echo a message when hours is +/- 100 before nexthours
and i want to echo when next hours is reached
and when next hours is more than hours.

i can do this with switch  but the calculation is the problem.

is there someone that can help me on the right way?

many thanks

edit====

i have a table with machine number with de next hours de machine need service, and the machine reports once in a while his hours. i have it almost solved now with this code

```
<?php
(abs($nexthours - $hours) 
?>
```

but now i have only the problem that if hours is 4710 and service is 4393 that it dont work i thinkk because he go to -

is there a solution for that?

Comment: This question is incomplete. 1. What does `$service_interval` represent? 2. When is this script called? 3. What does your attempt with "switch" look like?

Comment: Oh, I forgot: 4. Does `$hour` ever change in value? If so how?

Comment: I also find your question not clear enough. Usually, for cron type of jobs, it's easier to store an Unix timestamp for the next time you want to reach. The script just can compare the current Unix timestamp with the next one (which you store somewhere in a DB, file, session or whatever). You can print if it's soon reaching the next timestamp. Once it's equal or higher, you save the new next timestamp by adding the interval to the current timestamp.

Comment: $hour is specific for a machine so it change. 
see it like cars and to know when they need service in the garage. 

i have a list of machines with different machines every machine have a hour of the motor. and some machines need service every 500 hours some every 1000. i want to display a message next to the hours if service is needed. but then i need to calculate if service is needed or soon or he is above it

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way is to use:

```
if ( abs($next_hours - $hours) <=100)
    echo "Difference less than 100";
```

This condition will be met if the difference between the two values is +-100 or both values are equal

If you put more details, maybe we can come up with a better approach.

Comment: i use now (abs($nexthours - $hours) this workks fine many thanks for this solution

Comment: sure thing @Michael, 

I appreciate it if you can mark my solution as the right answer